# Get "No results" Message Custom Adapter ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am having a problem to set a "No results" message when getCount() returns 0.

I have a custom layout for the listview, and I simply want to get a "No Results" textview when there is no data on the listview.

Any idea how to achieve this?

I saw something with a empty id, but that needs to be on a listview, since this is a custom layout, it doesn't have that "tag".

Custom Adapter Code:

```
  public class ListScheduleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;

        protected List<Schedule> listSchedules;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ListScheduleAdapter(Context context, List<Schedule> listSchedules) {
            this.listSchedules = listSchedules;
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return listSchedules.size();
        }

        public Schedule getItem(int position) {
            return listSchedules.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return listSchedules.get(position).getCod_Horario();
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item,
                        parent, false);

                holder.txtTeacher = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_teacher);
                holder.txtDayofWeek = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_dayofweek);
                holder.txtSubject = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_subject);
                holder.txtTime = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
                holder.txtRoom = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_room);
                holder.txtClass = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_class);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Schedule sche = listSchedules.get(position);
            String fullTeacher = sche.getProfessor();
            String[] names = fullTeacher.split(" ");

            holder.txtTeacher.setText(names[0] + " " + names[names.length-1]);
            holder.txtDayofWeek.setText(sche.getDia_Semana());
            holder.txtSubject.setText(sche.getDisciplina());
            holder.txtTime.setText(sche.getT_Entrada() + "h-" + sche.getT_Saida()+"h");
            holder.txtRoom.setText(sche.getSala());
            holder.txtClass.setText(sche.getTurma());


            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTeacher;
            TextView txtDayofWeek;
            TextView txtSubject;
            TextView txtTime;
            TextView txtRoom;
            TextView txtClass;
        }

    }
```

Fragment Code (method called on a async OnPostExecute method):

```
private void populateListView() {

    ListScheduleAdapter adapter = new ListScheduleAdapter(getActivity(), ScheduleList);
    listviewHorarios.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_teacher"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_dayofweek"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_row2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_row1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_subject"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_time"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_row3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_row2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_room"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_class"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_data_available"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show where are you initializing `Adapter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_data_available"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

to the same layout where you declared your `ListView` (wrap both in a `FrameLayout`)

on the ListView's instance call

```
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
```

when the adapter is empty, you will see the `TextView` apper

Comment: Hi, since I got a custom adapterclass, how can I do this? I can't simply place "listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));" on the populateListView() method.

Comment: it is nothing related to the adapter. Add that line in your Activity/Fragment. ListView takes care of changing the visibility of the empty view

Comment: Yes, I understood that is not related to the adapter. Thanks it's working now, i had on the adapter layout, it's on the fragment layout that I have to put the empty field.

Answer (score 1):

add `TextView` to your `listview` layout and `setVisibility` of it to `GONE` and check the adapter:

```
if(adapter==null){
listView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
tvEmpty.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

hope this will help.